# turning an array of strings into a 2d array of chars

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, char, type-conversion

my code reads input from a file that has a maze written inside, inside the file looks like this.
    7 7
    GOOOOXO
    XXOXOOX
    OXOOOXX
    XXXOOXO
    XXXXOXX
    SOOOOOX
    XXXXXXX   (these are each on a separate line not sure how to show that here)

the numbers are the dimensions and G is goal S is start, that doesn't really matter for now. I read the file into an array of Strings line by line. So my array looks like this {"GOOOOXO",...,"XXXXXXX"} now I want to convert the strings to a 2d array of chars where the characters are stored the same way as the maze is displayed above.

The first nested for loop just reads the files input and saves each line as a string in the array, the second array is meant to convert the strings into characters to save them into the 2d array and still manage to keep the shape of the maze. I get an array index out of bounds exception. But to be honest with you after hours of being stuck on this my brain is fried, I can't figure out my issue.

```
    int dimensionsX = input.nextInt();
    int dimensionsY = input.nextInt();
    String[] lines = new String[dimensionsY];
    char[][] maze2 = new char[dimensionsX][dimensionsY];

    for (int j = 0; j < dimensionsY; ++j) {
        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            lines[j] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(lines[j]);
            //System.out.println(j);
        }

    }



    for (int i = dimensionsX; i > 0; --i) {
        for (int j = dimensionsY; j > 0; --i) {
            maze2[i][j] = lines[i].charAt(j);
            System.out.print(maze2[i][j]);
            if (i == lines.length) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: basicly: maze2[j]=input.nextLine().toCharArray(); (You may want to do some additional errorchecking )

Comment: this actually doesn't help me, in the first forloop I am saving the input in an array of strings, in the bottom part of my code in the for loop I am trying to take those strings and separate each string so that I save each character separately in a 2D array of chars in a way that keeps the shape of the maze. Im not sure what your comment is trying to do. Is it saving the input like in the char array but as characters?

Comment: the input files each have a different maze, with the number of rows and columns already given to us. which is why I have it set up like that. Now that I got past this issue I am getting an array index out of bounds exception

Comment: yes i overlooked one issue in your code and copied that, the inner loop needs to decrement j and not i.
"for (int j = dimensionsY; j > 0; --i) {" -> "for (int j = dimensionsY; j > 0; --j) {"

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
int dimensionsX = input.nextInt();
int dimensionsY = input.nextInt();
String[] lines = new String[dimensionsY];
char[][] maze2 = new char[dimensionsY][];

for (int j = 0; j < dimensionsY; ++j) {
    if (input.hasNextLine()) {
        lines[j] = input.nextLine();
        if(lines[j].length()<dimensionsX){
           System.err.println("we are doomed. Input malformed in line j: it has less then" + dimensionsX + "characters");
           System.exit(1);     
        }
        maze2[j] = lines[j].toCharArray();
        System.out.println(lines[j]);
        //System.out.println(j);
    }else{ 
       System.err.println("we are doomed. Input has too few lines");
       System.exit(1);
    }
}
//taken as is, but makes me wonder if it is intended to have dimensionsX as the Y coordinate but well...
for (int i = dimensionsX; i > 0; --i) {
    for (int j = dimensionsY; j > 0; --j) {
        System.out.print(maze2[j-1][i-1]);
    } 
    System.out.println();
}
```

Of course you want to do something different than exiting the program if the input is malformed e.g. throw an exception, or do nothing at all if your input is always correct(well is it?).